# wordpress - How integration of webservice with android app for all th content and pages

Tags: android, wordpress, web-services, web-applications

I have to implement web service for existing site with android application.I don't have any little bit idea about the process. please help me if anybody have and idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below is link which will help you to sort out your problem .
Here is all the steps are given in better way.

http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/08/11/make-your-wordpress-blog-a-web-service-in-few-step/

Answer (score 1):

```
There is a soap plugin framework for wordpress that allows you to create/expose wordpress behavior as soap api.
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00D1AYIG8][1] and
[http://github.com/patrickingle/wp-soap-services][2]

other wise please check this wordpress plugin
WordPress Web Service (WPWS) is used to access WordPress resources via WSDL and SOAP.
It allows you to connect WSDL enabled software like Adobe Flex / Flash Builder, Microsoft Visual Studio, PHP,
J2EE, etc. to WordPress resources like posts and pages
[https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-web-service/][3]


you can view more idea about wordpress webservice here
[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/embedding-a-soap-client-into-a-wordpress-plugin][4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use WordPress REST API (Version 2) plugin which fulfill your requirement and it is very easy to setup and understand.

Here is the link of plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/